# How many bytes in 1 block or 1 inode?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, filesystem

I'm trying to specify the amount of disk space for specific user in my Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 LTS System. I manually configure disk quota by editing /etc/fstab and add 2 more option next to the defaults option at the fourth field (e.g. usrquota and grpquota).

Then I use edquota command to specify the amount of disk space for my user

$ edquota -u user

After that, new screen has appeared and there are 2 kinds of size for specifying, e.g. blocks and inodes. I'm unaware of either. I only know the human readable size (e.g. KB, MB, GB and so on).

I will be happy if anyone can tell me what does inode means and how much size does it cost? and how much bytes in 1 block?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Block” is used with several different meanings: sometimes it's a number of bytes that depends on the filesystem, sometimes it's a number of bytes that depends on the application. The Linux quota tool uses a block size of 1024 bytes or 1 kilobyte. So to limit a user to 50MB you would set their limit to 50000 blocks.

As for inodes, one inode means one file (including directories), regarding of its size.

You can see the current disk usage with `df` (in kilobytes by default, you can switch to k/M/G/… prefixes with `-h` or `-B 4096` to show the number of 4096-byte blocks). To see the current inode usage, use `df -i`.